# Подмогите с решением на Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

> Дана последовательность натуральных чисел, завершающаяся числом 0. Определите, какое наибольшее число подряд идущих элементов этой последовательности равны друг другу.

У меня пока что получилось сделать только: сравнить текущий индекс со следующим, но как пройти дальше, чтобы найти максимальное количество повоторяющихся элементов не понимаю.

Пробую так:

```
let someInt = [23,23,4,6,23,45,6,7,23,23,23,0]
var someInt2 = someInt
var some = [Int]()
var indexX:Int = 0

for i in someInt {
    if i == someInt2[indexX+1] {
        some.append(i)
        some.append(someInt2[indexX+1])
        break
        print(some.count)
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, думаю, Вам подойдет следующее решение:

```
// Массив данных
let someInt = [23, 23, 4, 6, 23, 45, 6, 7, 23, 23, 23, 0]
// Максимальное число подряд идущих элементов
var count = 0
// Какое именно число идет подряд более всего раз
var int = 0
// Временная переменная для хранения длины текущей последовательности
var currentInt = -1
// Временная переменная для хранения текущего элемента последовательности
var currentCount = 0

for i in someInt {
    // Если текущий элемент равен записанному текущему - инкрементируем currentCount (++ убрали со Swift 3, вроде)
    if (i == currentInt) {
        currentCount += 1
    } else
    {
        // Если же текущий элемент не равен предыдущему, проверяем:
        // если длина текущей последовательности больше прошлой максимальной,
        // то обновляем данные
        if (currentCount > count) {
            count = currentCount
            int = currentInt
        }
        // Обновляем значение переменных, содержащих текущий элемент
        // и текущую длину последовательности
        currentInt = i
        currentCount = 1
    }
}

// Выводим результат
print("Число", int, "встретилось", count, "раза")
```

Вывод:

> Число 23 встретилось 3 раза

---

Или же можно вынести это все в отдельный метод. Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
// Массив данных
let someInt = [23, 23, 4, 6, 23, 45, 6, 7, 23, 23, 23, 0]

// Класс, содержащий информацию о последовательности
public class SequenceInfo
{
    public let Element : Int
    public let Count : Int

    public init(_ Element : Int, _ Count : Int)
    {
        self.Element = Element
        self.Count = Count
    }
}
// Расширение для строки, приводящее наш класс к строковому виду
extension String
{
    init(_ A : SequenceInfo)
    {
        self = "Элемент '\(A.Element)' встретился \(A.Count) разa"
    }
}

// Тело уже знакомой Вам функции
private func GetMaxSequenceLength(_ arr : Array<Int>) -> SequenceInfo
{
    var count = 0
    var int = 0
    var currentInt = -1
    var currentCount = 0
    for i in arr {
        if (i == currentInt) {
            currentCount += 1
        } else
        {
            if (currentCount > count) {
                count = currentCount
                int = currentInt
            }
            currentInt = i
            currentCount = 1
        }
    }
    return SequenceInfo(int, count)
}

// Вызов всего этого дела
print(String(GetMaxSequenceLength(someInt)))
```

Вывод:

> Элемент '23' встретился 3 разa

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам) Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: Спасибо, я правильно понимаю что все таки?:

// Временная переменная для хранения текущего элемента последовательности
var currentInt = -1
// Временная переменная для хранения длины текущей последовательности
var currentCount = 0

Comment: @ДимаДимов да, именно так) Мы держим в памяти предыдущий элемент последовательности и текущую длину его повторений. Если последовательность прерывается - все обнуляем)

Comment: попробовал добавить в массив другие повторения, например 
[23, 23, 4, 6, 23, 45, 6, 7, 23, 23, 23,45,45,45,45,45,45]
Все равно выводит что 23 повторяется 3 раза, хотя должен найти "45"x 5. Получается что после повторения, в любом случае должна быть еще какое либо значение

Comment: @poterok вы ведь сказали, что массив оканчивается на нуль. Если без него, то после цикла нужно ещё раз провести проверку на `currentCount > count`

Comment: спсибо, теперь отложилось)

Comment: @poterok был рад помочь)